# Open ELEC iplayer

Tags: openelec

I downloaded the iplayer zip file from https://github.com/joolswills/plugin.video.iplayer and when I unzip it on OpenELEC "Frodo" everything works, but when I try to look for videos it comes up saying *"(no programmes available - try again later)"* and I have an internet connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your version of [Kodi/XBMC](https://kodi.tv/download/) (OpenELEC) is really old and no longer supported!
also the [iplayer](https://github.com/joolswills/plugin.video.iplayer) you use is no longer maintained!

please use the new [iPlayer WWW](https://github.com/vonH/plugin.video.iplayerwww/releases/) instead! - for problems with this plugin go to this forum: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=239378

Comment: What version of kodi/XMBC should I use because I am running it on a raspberry pi b 512MB of ram.

Comment: well, i use the recent Kodi 15.x on a RPi B+ without any problem! -- please use at least the recent [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec) 5.0.8 (Kodi 14.2) or [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/) 2015.09-2 (Kodi 15.1) with the default Kodi-skin [Confluence](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Confluence)! - some other skins may be completely unusable because of their ram-usage!